# Send element's id as url parameter in jQuery autocomplete source

Tags: jquery, user-interface, autocomplete

I'm trying to do something like so:

```
$("[type=text]").autocomplete({
    source: "./json.php?id="+$(this).attr("id"),
    minLength: 2
}).addClass("ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-left");
```

Obviously the `source: "./json.php?id="+$(this).attr("id")` doesn't work.  Does anyone know how I can do this?  There will be many autocomplete fields so I can't use a selector like `$('#ID')`.

Comment: Have a look at my post, you have an interesting test case, see if any of my suggestions improve performance, or if they work at all. :)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, I'll give them a try.  As I said in my comment under your answer, I'm reconsidering using jQuery's autocomplete altogether.  I might explore other plugins but I don't really want to spend the extra time experimenting as this project needs to get done.  I'll most likely accomplish the autocomplete fields the old fashioned way - good ol' `< ... onKeyup() .../>` and handle everything via custom CSS and JS. Wish it didn't have to come down to this though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you need to set this for many elements at the same time, use an `each()` loop:

```
$("[type=text]").each(function() {
    var thisEl = $(this);
    thisEl.autocomplete({
        source: "./json.php?id=" + thisEl.attr("id"),
        minLength: 2
    });
    // whatever else you want to do with the element
});
```

Comment: How come I don't have to for the `select:` option?  Is it because the select: is called afterward?

Comment: NM, I had tried this before but I remember that I decided against using .each because I thought that it was really impacting performance, but I just tested it and it only adds about 1-3 sec to the load time (1,500+ autocomplete fields).

Comment: 1500? Wow I'd love to know what kind of app this is

Answer (score 5):

You have to iterate through them using `.each()` to execute `.attr()` in proper scope:

```
$("input[type=text]").each(function(){
    $(this).autocomplete({
        source: "./json.php?id="+$(this).attr("id"),
        minLength: 2
    }).addClass("ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-left");
}
```

**Edit:** As mentioned in a comment, you have a *LOT* of fields, like 1500+. You might try improve performance by adding a class to each field, and using the `.classname` selector, or at least narrow down the initial search to `input[type="text"]`, although jQuery might do that already for optimization.

You might also try setting the source option in the `create` or `search` events of the autocomplete, although the latter might not work. Doesn't hurt to see how it performs:

```
$("input[type=text]").autocomplete({
    search: function(){
        $(this).autocomplete("option", "source", "./json.php?id="+$(this).attr("id"));
    },
    minLength: 2
}).addClass("ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-left");
```

Alternatively you can even bind into the focus event of the input field itself to set the source:

```
$("input[type=text]").autocomplete({
    minLength: 2
}).focus(function(){
    $(this).autocomplete("option", "source", "./json.php?id="+$(this).attr("id"));
}).addClass("ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-left");
```

See if any of those improve performance, it's an interesting test case you've got there.

Comment: Actually narrowing by class seems to help a little bit, the real test will come when I make the remaining fields autocompletes as well - right now there can be any where from 1,000 - 2,000 fields, multiply that by 4 (or even 7 depending on what I determine) and that will be the end result.  I'm starting to consider other options as 1,500 takes about 9 seconds to load, I might not want to find out what 10,000+ does to the load time!